# Selenium search within attribute

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to add `.click()` to this line of HTML using `Selenium webdriver` (PhantomJS).
I am new to Selenium and can't find a way to distinctly click on search within attribute such as below (see HTML).

Using the following `find_element_by..` is not specific enough. The only unique part is the attribute value.

- find_element_by_id
- find_element_by_name
- find_element_by_xpath
- find_element_by_link_text
- find_element_by_partial_link_text
- find_element_by_tag_name
- find_element_by_class_name
- find_element_by_css_selector

```html
<td onclick="show_ad('2','1','/Nadlan/salesDetails.php','ElemID','339efe7a8643d231c48098cc593e3705f13','644');" >Elems</td>
```

Comment: Please post the full table html.It would help in creating relative xpath. You can try this xpath //td[contains(.,'Elems')]

Comment: <div class="main_table_wrap">
        <table class="main_table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
            <tr>
         <td onclick="show_ad('2','1','/Nadlan/salesDetails.php','ElemID','6b446996aefe0baea528378f6550a5f441b','644');" >
             Elem         </td>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>

Comment: Try if this xpath works: //table[@class='main_table']//td[contains(.,'Elem')]  The class name with <table> attribute seems to be unique so this xpath identifies the table with class name='main_table' and then finds the <td> attribute which contains 'Elem'.

Comment: do you get `NoSuchElement` exception or your code (provide it also) just do nothing?